# solved cameras track points are selectable in viewport?

Tags: tracking

[image]

I have solved camera and when I want to select something like empties belonging to the camera,

How do I select some of them together in 3d viewport??
I can select only one by one.

And also If Is it possible, How can I resize those empties and export those as FBX?